# How to deselect the radio button?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

How can I deselect the radio button when page loads. At the moment when the page loads it is selecting the first option as a default option. These are the codes so far I have tried.

### register.js

```
class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.setSex('male', 'female');
    }

    render() {
         return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Item style={{ height: 55 }}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: '#fff' }}>{t('account_gender')}  </Text>
                          <RadioGroup flexDirection='row' style={{ color: '#fff' }} radioButtons={this.props.login.sex} onPress={() => this.props.onChangeSex()} />
                    </View>
               </Item>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

### reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    login :{
        sex: [
            {label: 'male', value: 1, size: 20, color: '#fff', selected: false},{label: 'female', value: 2, size: 20, color: '#fff', selected: false}
        ],
    }
}
export default function reducer (state = initialState, action){

    switch(action.type){
        case 'SETSEX' :
            let sex = {...state.login}
            sex.sex[0].label = action.male
            sex.sex[1].label = action.female
            return{
                ...state,
                login : sex
            }
        case 'CHANGESEX' :
            let selectedSex = state.login.sex.find(e => e.selected == true);
            selectedSex = selectedSex ? selectedSex.value : state.login.sex[0].label;
            return{
                ...state,
            }
}
return state
}
```

### Actions/login.js

```
export function setSex(male, female) {
    return (dispatch) => dispatch({type: 'SETSEX', male, female})
}

export function onChangeSex() {
    return (dispatch) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGESEX'})
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? It's too hard to diagnose the problem with the code provided

Comment: Thanks - can you include the definiton for `onChangeSex()`

Comment: also, what package are you using for `RadioGroup` ?

Comment: @DacreDenny I have updated the question and I am using "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^1.0.7",

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144013/5995973

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues causing your code to fail. First, revise your `render()` method like so:

```
<RadioGroup flexDirection='row' style={{ color: '#fff' }} 
            radioButtons={this.props.login.sex} 
            onPress={ (data) => this.props.onChangeSex(data) } /> {/* Add data parameter */}
```

Next, update your `onChangeSex()` dispatcher to account for the added parameter:

```
/* Add data parameter */
export function onChangeSex(data) {

    return (dispatch) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGESEX', data })
}
```

And finally, update your reducer to account for the actions data parameter:

```
export default function reducer (state = initialState, action){

    switch(action.type){
        case 'SETSEX' : {
            let sex = {...state.login}
            sex.sex[0].label = action.male
            sex.sex[1].label = action.female
            return{
                ...state,
                login : sex
            }
        }
        case 'CHANGESEX' : {

            /* Update reducer */
            return{
                ...state,
                login : { sex : action.data }
            }
        }
     }

     return state
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No its still the same

Comment: just to confirm, are you sure the reducer is being called correctly? are you able to place a `debugger` statement in the ` case 'CHANGESEX' : {` block? does the debugger hit that break point?